# Can I lock and unlock a fifo (named pipe) in C?

Tags: c, pipe, nonblocking

I have two progress, `p1` and `p2`, and a named pipe `var` for ipc between 2 progress.
I want to lock `var`'s rw for `p2` when `p1` writes, and unlock `var` when `p1` finished write.

ps:

I using select for nonblocking, so `p2` will get readable when `p1` put anything to `var`.Can I let `var` become readable when `p1` finish write?

Comment: Did you try to put your thoughts and come up with some design ?

Comment: On POSIX systems (like Linux and OSX) named pipes are files in the file system, and files can be locked. Though I don't know if they will work for pipes. Have you tried to search for file locking functions?

Comment: Now I have a big amount of data, and I need write it to pipe.
but another progress shouldnt read it until all data has written

Comment: I using select for nonblocking, and `p2` will identify pipe is readable when `p1` put anything to pipe, althought it not completely written of whole data.

Comment: Remember that a pipe is not limitless, it can fill up and block the writing application.

Comment: When I lock file that means `p1` and `p2` both cant write?
I only want lock for `p2`.

Comment: Use two pipes? One for p1-to-p2 communication, and one for p2-to-p1 communication.

Comment: you mean one as signal, the other as data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use signals (e.g. `SIGUSR1`). The writer makes it pipe non-blocking (so it won't block when the pipe becomes full), writes until it can't write anymore, then send the signal to the other process. The reading process reads all (from its non-blocking pipe), then sends a signal to the writer who then continues to write.

However, this is really not needed. The writer can just write, and the reader just read. If the pipe becomes full the writer will block until it can write more. And the same for the reader, it will block if there's nothing to read. Then when the writer has written all data, it will simply close its end of the pipe, which the reader will detect with a `read` call that returns zero bytes read.

Comment: File lock give me some sense. I will test fcntl later.

Comment: I think I need to use two pipes, one for signal, the other for data.
I just try to lock, but I cant lock. Maybe cant lock `mkfifo`'s file?

Comment: @KaMeTang I suspected it was not possible to lock the FIFO file. And yes, one pipe for data in one direction, and one pipe for commands (or signals) in the other.